# How do we get the mouse canvas relative x,y coordinates from an onClick event?

Tags: canvas, dart

I have found the following code from https://github.com/sethladd/bad-aliens-dart/blob/master/web/Game.dart :

```dart
    ClientRect rect = ctx.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    clientBoundingRect = new GamePoint(rect.left, rect.top);
...
    GamePoint getXandY(e) {
      num x =  e.clientX - clientBoundingRect.x - (ctx.canvas.width/2);
      num y = e.clientY - clientBoundingRect.y - (ctx.canvas.height/2);
      return new GamePoint(x, y);
    }
```

I have tested but it does not calculate the proper mouse position in the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CanvasElement.getBoundingRect()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/CanvasElement.html#getBoundingClientRect) now returns a `Rect` rather than a `ClientRect`.  Otherwise, the code appears to work properly for me.

**Update:** Note that Bad Aliens places the origin in the center of the Canvas.  Perhaps you want to leave it in the upper left?  If so, then don't subtract half the canvas dimensions:

```dart
GamePoint getXandY(e) {
  num x =  e.clientX - clientBoundingRect.x;
  num y = e.clientY - clientBoundingRect.y;
  return new GamePoint(x, y);
}
```